# Filter on Appointment,Meeting and Online Meeting items in OutLook-2010

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to write a macro in VBA that will give me all the items from the above mentioned category.
I can be able to find all the AppointItems. How can i find the others?
Any Idea?

Set objExpCal=objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer

Set objNavMod=objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)

Set objNavGroup =objNavMod.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olPeopleFoldersGroup)

For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders

Set objFolder = objNavFolder.Folder

Set oItems = objFolder.Items

For Each MyItem In oItems

If (MyItem.Start >= dateintxtbox1 and MyItem.Start <= dateintxtbox2 ) Then

'write in excelsheet code

end if

next

next

Comment: show the code which you already have as starting point...

Comment: i want to add all the appoinment items including the recurring items within the specified date range into excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A MeetingItem is a particular subtype of an OlAppointmentItem. For a given AppointmentItem, if the MeetingStatus property of the object is true, then it is a Meeting and will be recieved in the inbox as such.

Please see: [MSDN MeetingItem Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.meetingitem%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and
[MSDN _AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.meetingstatus%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If it's the IPM message classes that you are looking for - here is a list: [list of message classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204771%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

I do not know what an "online meeting" item is - I don't think it's different from a normal meeting. Maybe it's just a meeting that has some sort of livemeeting link in the content?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for your time..My major requirement is the recurring meeting item, I add the line item.includerecurrence=true in my code still i am unable to findout the object of that item. An example is such that if the recurring item is scheduled from some date in 2011 and it will occur on every wednesday, When i entered some date range, I just want to check is there any recurring item found in the    range or not if found include that item with other appointments. I think this example may clear all your doubts. Thanks.